# PHP/MySQL foreign keys saves as id=0 to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, silex

I'm new to php and mysql but there is a project I have to do on my classes with Silex 2.0 and Symfony and I have problems with my php code and foreign keys in my products table in database.

The problem is with proper way of save functions in my program.

Here's what happens in my data base when I try to add or edit new product - I get idCategory and idProducent = 0. :/

And there is part of my code in ProductModel.php responsible for saving it to database(to table products):

> ```
> public function addProduct($data)
> {
>     $sql = 'INSERT INTO 
>                 `products` ( `id`, `idCategory`, `idProducent`, `name`,  `price_netto`, `price_brutto`, `desc` ) 
>             VALUES 
>                 (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
>     $data['price_netto'] = $data['price_brutto'] * 1.22;
>     $this->_db->executeQuery(
>         $sql, array(
>         $data['idCategory'], $data['idProducent'], $data['name'], 
>         $data['price_netto'], $data['price_brutto'], $data['desc'])
>     );
> }
> ```

```
public function saveProduct($data)
{
    if (isset($data['id']) && ctype_digit((string)$data['id'])) {
        $sql = "UPDATE 
                    products 
                SET 
                    idCategory = ?, idProducent = ?, name = ?, 
                    price_netto = ?, price_brutto = ?, `desc` = ? 
                WHERE 
                    id = ?";
        $data['price_netto'] = $data['price_brutto'] * 1.22;
        $this->_db->executeQuery(
            $sql, array(
            $data['idCategory'], $data['idProducent'], $data['name'], 
            $data['price_netto'], $data['price_brutto'], $data['desc'], $data['id'])
        );
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                    `products` ( `id`, `idCategory`, `idProducent`, `name`, `price_netto`, `price_brutto`, `desc` ) 
                VALUES 
                    (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $data['price_netto'] = $data['price_brutto'] * 1.22;
        $this->_db->executeQuery(
            $sql, array($data['id']), array(
            $data['idCategory'], $data['idProducent'], $data['name'], 
            $data['price_netto'], $data['price_brutto'], $data['desc'])
        );        
    }
}
```

Here you have ProductController.php [the part I think is important here]:
https://codeshare.io/5w4rRD

Also functions from ProducentsModel.php and CategoriesModel.php:

```
public function getProducents()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM producents;';
    return $this->_db->fetchAll($sql);
}
public function getCategories()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM categories;';
    return $this->_db->fetchAll($sql);
}
```

Sorry for giving you only links but this is my first time with Stack Overflow, hope you'll understand.

Comment: can you share your table structure?

Comment: http://screenshot.sh/oe5YXJ1HXU3Jq
http://screenshot.sh/n9GN2B179sVUM

Comment: Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: I am using InnoDB

Comment: You are missing FK constriants

Comment: I guess it's not it - earlier on the version 1.2 of Silex it was working fine. But I have updated libriares and I fight with bugs right now. Netherless it worked without constraints. But I check it.

Comment: Use a tool like HeidiSQL to build your schema and setup FK constraints, etc...makes life much easier :)

Comment: I did what you said and I added foreign keys of tables Categories and Products and here is wha I have: screenshot.sh/mE94ENVCQ2zgE screenshot.sh/m7wozmtmkH41y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database was fine. The bug was in ProductController.php which you can find in link up there. This is how it suppose to look like in both edit and add options:

> for ( $i=0; $test[$i] != NULL; $i++) {
>               $choiceCategory[$test[$i]['name']] = $test[$i]['id'];;
>           }

```
    $producentModel = new ProducentsModel($app);
    $test = $producentModel->getProducents();

    $choiceProducent = array();

    for ( $i=0; $test[$i] != NULL; $i++) {
        $choiceProducent[$test[$i]['name']] = $test[$i]['id'];
    }
```

And delete this: `choice_label` until `placeholder=>'Choose'`.

Sorry for bothering you guys and thank you for quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy this verbatim but your SQL is missing something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  id INT UNISIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

  ... missing part below

  CONSTRAINT `FKID_CATEGORY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`idCategory`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idCategory` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `idProducent` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` char(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `price_netto` float NOT NULL,
  `price_brutto` float unsigned NOT NULL,
  `desc` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_products_1` (`idCategory`),
  KEY `FK_products_2` (`idProducent`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_products_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idCategory`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_products_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idProducent`) REFERENCES `producents` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Comment: I did what you said and I added foreign keys of tables Categories and Products and here is wha I have:
http://screenshot.sh/mE94ENVCQ2zgE
http://screenshot.sh/m7wozmtmkH41y

Comment: That is to be expected. The integrity constraint is what is preventing you from deleting a parent and leaving it's "children" lingering as phantom records. The FK needs to be NULL if the two can exist independently.

Comment: Post the dump of your SQL schema - in text form so I can copy and paste quickly :)

Comment: OK so I imported your schema - I see you have some FK setup - what table specifically are you having issues with? orders_products? Once you apply FK you can no longer run those INSERT statements?

Comment: I have problems with products - in products you have idCategory and idProducent. When I try to add product or edit product errors appear.
Maybe we can change this conversation to chat? I would send you more screenshots of the problem.

Comment: The thing is those INSERTs in database, they are there, I can see the records. But when I try to edit them or to add new in my project[website] i get the errors you saw in my screens.

Comment: Try updating your schema given the code I added above??? the FK are now nullable - if that is not the desired result then you need to make sure you specify them both. More importantly you cannot create a product linked to a category ID that doesn't exist